# Python on HDInsight

Tags: c#, python, azure-hdinsight

I'm running a Random Forest algorithm, with a Python script on HDInsight.
I create a custom HDInsight cluster from C# code.

For running the script I make a remote desktop connection to the cluster and run it from the command line.

I want to run the python script from the c# code so I can delete the cluster as soon as I finish.

Does anybody know how to do this.

Comment: See the anwser of Tao Li http://stackoverflow.com/a/29837310/2269997

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Random Forest algorithm is being run as a MapReduce job, you should be able to use the example at: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/#submit-hadoop-streaming-jobs-using-hdinsight-net-sdk to submit a streaming job that calls your Python code as Mapper and Reducer.

If this is not the case, can you explain how the code is being started when you launch it locally on the cluster via RDP?

Comment: The Python code uses spark. (both spark and python are installed by a custom script. We open the command prompt on the remote desktop and run this:  spark-submit pythoncode.py".

Comment: There is not currently a way to launch Spark commands from the SDK, but you might be able to leverage an almost empty Hive script to get this started.  Hive allows you to launch arbitrary commands like `! spark-submit pythondoce.py;`.  This is obviously a bit of a workaround, but might suffice for your purposes.  You will lose one container's worth of capacity for the Templeton controller job that runs the Hive script, and you will have to see if the expected output is available to the job.  The Hive command will run on a random workernode, so spark-submit must be available on all nodes.

Comment: also found a solution using oozie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28542415/remotely-execute-a-spark-job-on-an-hdinsight-cluster